# How to add onBlur to function on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add onblur function to html code inside in my javascript code and below my code is not working. can anyone advice me on this please

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 
    var fname_lname = ' <div class="form-group"><label for="inputRegNo" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" style="text-align: left;"></label><input class="special-block" type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="Name" onblur="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+='<br/>'+ this.value"    />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="special-block" type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" /><button href="#" class="remove_field">-</button></div>'

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(fname_lname); 
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){          
     e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 
    var fname_lname = ' <div class="form-group"><label for="inputRegNo" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" style="text-align: left;"></label><input class="special-block" type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="Name" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="special-block" type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" /><button href="#" class="remove_field">-</button></div>'

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(fname_lname); 
            $(wrapper).on("blur", "special-block", function() {
                document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+='<br/>'+ this.value
            })
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){          
     e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: data not storing in  <p id="refa5"> </p> printing section.please advice

Answer (score 1):

**First**:

I think your problem is here:

```
var fname_lname = ' <div class="form-group"><label for="inputRegNo" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" style="text-align: left;"></label><input class="special-block" type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="Name" onblur="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+='<br/>'+ this.value"    />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="special-block" type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" /><button href="#" class="remove_field">-</button></div>'
```

After hlaf of the line you have this:`'refa5'` and this `'<br/>'` that have broken your string. and after this line, your code does not work.

**Second**: To set an event to an **appended** element, you can not do this by add text in front of element. This is not true:

```
<input class="special-block" type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="Name" onblur="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+='<br/>'+ this.value"    />
```

You must use binding:

```
$('.special-block').on('blur', function(){
   document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+='<br/>'+ $(this).value;
}
```

Do not forget to replace `this.value` with `$(this).value`.